# How can I add minus sign in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code :-

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<span class="display"></span>
```

My jquery code :

```
$("#test").keyup(function(e){
  $('span.display').text(formatCurrency($(this).val()));
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

Demo and full code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/nbLbb037/

I want the input text can enter this : `-10000000`

And the result who displayed in class display is : `-10.000.000`

How can I add minus (`-`) sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change code like below:-

```
output = output.reverse();
if(output[1] == '.'){
   output.splice(1, 1);
   formatted = output.join("");
}else{
   formatted = output.join("");
}
```

And every thing will be fine.

Example:-

```js
$("#test").keyup(function(e){
  
  $('span.display').text(formatCurrency($(this).val()));
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g,'');
});


// format currency on pagu and revisi
var formatCurrency = function(num){
    var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
    if(str.indexOf(",") > 0) {
        parts = str.split(",");
        str = parts[0];
    }
    str = str.split("").reverse();
    for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
        if(str[j] != ".") {
            output.push(str[j]);
            if(i%3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                output.push(".");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
     output = output.reverse();
     if(output[1] == '.'){
        output.splice(1, 1);
        formatted = output.join("");
     }else{
        formatted = output.join("");
     }
    return(formatted + ((parts) ? "," + parts[1].substr(0, 1) : ""));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
<span class="display"></span>
```

Comment: It looks weird. You try input this : `-100000`. The result `-.100.000`. Should the result this : `-100.000`

Comment: if that line is removed then you can add anything in textbox like. -23sfd.sdf83243. which will make it worse.

Comment: @samueltoh  please check answer now. Ashokkumar M. Prajapati i have added the line(you are right) and changed the code so that it worked.

Comment: "-62.621.22-.151.522.1-5.52-" is allowed. This will never make sense. Only solution will be using regular expression to allow "$,.-" with their proper allowed position. Or a large logical modification is required.

Answer (score 0):

adding a minus sign is very easy, just replace

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
```

with following

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.-]/g,'');
```

updated js fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/nbLbb037/3/

But. You need to use regular expression test to verify exact currency test. Try exploring js regular expression test for your "formatCurrency" function. Of course thats purly upto you. Current solution will let you move further.

I have updated the regular expression js code on fiddle. Refer to https://jsfiddle.net/nbLbb037/5/

Comment: It looks weird. You try input this : `-100000`. The result `-.100.000`. Should the result this : `-100.000`

Comment: that is why i told to make it regular expression test. what you are doing is replacing all the character except the one you specified.

Comment: remember this new js expression code will let you enter data where "-" can be there but optional and number 11111.1111 where you can only have one single ".". you are not allowed to add "," in it. You can modify regular expression as per your need.

Comment: I had see you update jsfiddle. but it does not work. I see Alive to Die answer. It works